# How can I identify which alternator is the right one?

Tags: vw, alternator, golf, part-identification

I need a replacement alternator for my 1993 VW Mk1 Cabriolet (aka Rabbit).

Unfortunately, the identifications on the old alternator are painted over. I cant ID it.

On sites I've looked at there seems to be about 6 different alternators for the same car.

How can I ID which is the right one for me?

Engine is 1.6lt SOHC K-Jetronic (injected). Same engine as late model Mk1 GTIs. There is no air-con. In fact the only power option is the roof.

Many thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the details of the engine?

Comment: Two things: First, can you post a picture of the back side of the alternator, where the wires attach. The connections will tell the tale. Second, does your VW come with or without AC?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 it's a no AC model. 

I've added images above. The 2nd is what appears to be a capacitor, if that's any help.

Comment: @Appleman cheers mate, I've added it above

Comment: I think you have your response concerning witch one is your replacement, but maybe you can get it rebuild much faster than acquiring a new one, cheaper and more environnement friendly :) In my region, there are quite a few store that rebuild them. Maybe you could even do it yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the following are rebuilt replacements for your alternator:

- WPS/Power Select PN: 14970N
- Pure Energy PN: 14778
- Remy PN: 14918

The difference (it appears) between the AC to non-AC unit is the Amperage output: AC=90A; non-AC=65A. You will probably want to get a replacement alternator which has the capacitor (externally connected part as you've described) already installed.

Comment: Ah, so I'm guessing this one might work? https://au.vwheritage.com/shop/golf-cabriolet/068903017MX/alternator-65amp-see-description-for-applications/?crumbStartPage=1&crumbStartRow=1

Comment: @MeltingDog - It looks like the right one, but look at the lead time of 4 weeks. You may want to find a different source.

Comment: Ah so the capcitor dictates the Amp output? Can't I just reuse the old one?

Comment: @MeltingDog - I don't think it does. I'm just suggesting getting one already installed so you know you have a good one, versus having to purchase a new one or having the old one go out. Not necessary, but a good thing none the less.

Comment: @Paulster just read then that its job is to even out the current from the alternator so as not to hurt the battery

Comment: The capacitor is for alternator noise suppression. It would not affect the output or determine the rating. If you hear alternator whine in the radio then the capacitor is bad. If not, reuse the capacitor and save a little coin.

Answer (score 1):

You need a 65 Amps, 125 mm Stator Diameter, 12 V alternator. The exact one is mentioned in the link:

[VW Rabbit 1.6 Non AC alternator](http://www.autozone.com/batteries-starting-and-charging/alternator/duralast-alternator/871285_188976_4423/)